# Vuejs http request always attach a query parameter

Tags: vuejs2, vue-resource

Am using a query param authentication with my backed that requires all http requests have the following

```
access-token=token
```

AM using vuejs2 resource

So in my request i want to intercept every request and attach the above so i have

```
   Vue.http.interceptors.push(function (request, next) {
        //here add the access token in my url string
        //am stuck
        next()
    });
```

So i expect when i try

```
this.$http.get('users')
```

the request should automatically be

```
users?access-token=token
```

Also when ihave

```
this.$http.get('users?pagination=10')
```

then request url should have

```
users?pagination=10&access-token=token
```

How do i intercept all the requests and attach the query parameter access token

Comment: Should implement it in the backend as to get it from headers, then you can use `request.headers.set('access-token', localStorage.getItem('access-token'));` etc

Answer (score 0):

THe way i was able to resolve this was by

```
     if(request.url.indexOf("?") === -1){ //means no access token since nothing is passed to the url
        request.url = request.url+"?access-token=token";
      }else{
        if(request.url.indexOf("access-token") === -1){
            request.url = request.url+"&access-token=token"
        }
      }
```